# Jquery after() quotes anomaly

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Im trying to do this :

When i add a student through my UI , using AJAX a row should get appended to the existing list(table) of students

So the feilds of my UI i sent to my controller, finished the db entry , from my controller i pass a Json object containing all the fields i want to show to my view (This is all working perfect).

In my view i did

```
success : function(result){
res = eval('('+result+')');
//Here the problem, begins , appending a row to the existing table:
$('#my_table tr:last').after('<tr>
<td>'+res.name+'</td>
<td>'+res.address+'</td>
<td><a href="javascript:void(0)">'+ res.flag== true ? "Male" : "Female" +'</a></td> // this is where im stuck !
</tr>')
}
```

The output is , it honestly checks for the flag value ie if flag== true it prints male , but its not displaying a link AND the gender is the ONLY thing that is displayed , not the name and address

If i remove the line

```
 <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">'+ res.flag== true ? "Male" : "Female" +'</a></td>
```

It prints the name and address correctly, and if i add the line for checking the gender it prints ONLY The gender and it is NOT anchor Tagged , like its not a link

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using this

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">'+ (res.flag== true ? "Male" : "Female") +'</a>
```

just a difference of brackets but might do the thing

Comment: There is no need to use `true` in conditional operator.

Comment: This will work. If you leave out the brackets, you're essentially doing `'<tr>...' + res.flag == true` which will always evaluate to true (a non-empty string is true in JavaScript).

Comment: but res.flag im assuming is boolean

Comment: @user1537158 - dont forget to upvote OR mark as ans if it helped